# tzset + setting TZ env variable doesn't work under windows

Tags: perl, timezone, localtime

I'm trying to get current NY time. This code works under Linux, but gives local time under windows.

```
use POSIX qw(tzset);

sub is_time
{
    $ENV{TZ} = 'America/New_York';
    tzset();

    my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = localtime();
    if (($hour > 9 && $hour < 14) || ($hour == 9 && $min > 30))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative way to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

```
use DateTime qw( );

my $dt = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'America/New_York' );
return $dt->hour > 9 && $dt->hour < 14 || $dt->hour == 9 && $dt->minute > 30;
```

Comment: I would if I could, but that library isn't available. Yes, adding it is probably the only alternative.

Comment: Yes, I meant that I have to install it, but I need it in lots of boxes, so it's not that straightforward.

Comment: You can zip up the `blib` directory obtained from `perl MakeFile.PL ; make` and simply copy it to machines with the same Perl setup.

Comment: Yes I can, but I think there must be some way to do it without DateTime library.

Comment: Sure, you could use something worse. I can't think of any other module other than DateTime::TimeZone that provides time zone data, but you might be able to find one if you looked. Also, there's gotta be a web site you could screen scrape.

Comment: Yes, I agree that DateTime is the best way, but for my case installing that library isn't preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't use Olson timezones.

Try `$ENV{TZ} = 'EST5EDT';`

For example,

```
use feature qw( say );
use POSIX qw( tzset );
for my $tz (qw( EST5EDT PST8PDT )) {
   local $ENV{TZ} = $tz;
   tzset();
   say("$tz: ", scalar(localtime));
}
```

Output:

```
EST5EDT: Tue Aug 22 22:14:04 2017
PST8PDT: Tue Aug 22 19:14:04 2017
```

Comment: @user1289 is it possible you are doing this under apache?  show what you tried that didn't work